# Best schema to find items according to multiple criterias

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, schema

I'm creating a website using Symfony2 and I want my users to see a list of items according to their profile. I am looking for the best way to do that.

The users have basic fields attached to their profile (first name, email, etc.) but I want to add some specific information: gender, income, interests (so different types : bool, integer, string etc). Some fields and values may be added, modified or deleted later.

The items will have criteria so that they will be shown to the corresponding users according to the users' profile.

Actually it is a bit like a shopping website with information attached to products and then the client can reduce the number of items shown thanks to a list of criteria.

I thought of putting an array with the different criteria and values in the User entity but I find this solution really bad.

Do you have an idea of what might be the best Entity/DB schema to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is filtering, your query which you use to get your product is the one you should play with not the user.

As i understood you want to show different product to each user depending on their gender etc..

You will need some kind of link to know which product to show to which user? Which information you want to check in the product side? you can have an entity linked to product with different information like gender male for a product that you will use in your query to get all `select * from product where product.criteria.gender = user.gender` this is just a simplified query but it is a bit more tricky with a join if you want to do it in SQL or DQL